# Center nested boxplots in Python/Seaborn with unequal classes

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I have grouped data from which I want to generated boxplots using seaborn. However, not every group has all classes. As a result, the boxplots are not centered if classes are missing within one group:
[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlGsZ.png)

The graph is generated using the following code: 
`sns.boxplot(x="label2", y="value", hue="variable",palette="Blues")`

Is there any way to force seaborn to center theses boxes? I didn't find any approbiate way. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is but you are not going to like it.
Centering these will mean that you will have the same y value for median values, so normalize your data so that the median is 0.5 for each y value for each value of x. That will give you the plot you want, but you should note that somewhere in the plot so people will not be confused.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your suggestion. However it doesn't seem to work [Figure](https://imgur.com/VaapGJv) Now the median of all groups is 0.5 but the boxes are still very off-centered. Any further idea what do do?

Comment: Your image in the comment looks right to me. Perhaps I misunderstood your question. Do you need to have enough space for 4 boxes for each x value regardless of how many  groups you have (assuming the maximum number of classes is 4)?